# How to move div to all directions

Tags: javascript, jquery

> I want to move a div slightly in all directions when corresponding button is
>   clicked(Move to top when top button is clicke,move to left when left
>   button is clicked....etc).Hoe i can do this in jQuery

Please help me .Thanks in advance...

Comment: Check out the [ScrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) plugin.

Comment: @ZaneM. can i ask another question

Comment: Of course! Also, if you only need a slight movement and where you want the window to move has an id you can always make the button an anchor and the href `#id`

Comment: actually my requirement is to move to up,down,right,left directions depending on the button is pressed.Is there any plugin for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.right').click(function() {
    $(".wrap").animate({ scrollLeft: "+=50" }, "slow");
    return false;
});

$('.down').click(function() {
    $(".wrap").animate({ scrollTop: "+=50" }, "slow");
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3xaPz/1/

Comment: Updated answer with right and down, but you can change it as you see fit (it's the same pattern).

Comment: i am looking for this from past 5 hrs

Comment: I'm glad we finally sorted that out. :D